# PyQt5 a dash in checkbox not a ✓when I setCheckState(True)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]
As The pic shows, a dash line in checkbox not a tick. And I have to click to make it a tick, how can I fix it?

```
...
group_list = QListWidget(self)
for i in range(2):
    group = QListWidgetItem(str(i))
    group.setCheckState(1)
    group_list.addItem(group)       
...
```

ps: PyQt5.9.2

Comment: You can use the platform independent Fusion style by `QApplication.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: How does your code even execute? `QListWidgetItem` has no member function `setCheckState`

Comment: @replete [Yes it does](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setCheckState).

Answer (score 2):

I find it out, Just setCheckState explicity

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
...
group.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
....
```